# Azure Cloud Service : Scaled in web site (web role) instance recieves requests before iis is ready

Tags: iis, azure, azure-cloud-services

**Description**

I got a web role hosted in a cloud service that is a web site.
There are predictible load spikes that we handle with a custom monitoring (a worker role) that will periodically scale in or scale out depending on the predicted load profile.
That part is working.

**Issue**

After a new instance of the web site is mounted by the monitoring, we just had a case of a user whose request reach that new instance before the new instance was fully load. It resulted in an unaccessible web site blank page on the web browser. Given our typical target client it is very bad.
This happen when a tester connected (for the first time) to the web site approximately during the scale in process.

Do my question is, is there a way to ensure that a web role has fully loaded IIS7, started the apppools and finished all the web site warmup process before any request is directed to it?
Or in a more general way, can we manualy decide wich instance is available to the load balancer ? by that I mean that I assume there is a built-in load balancer over a cloud service automaticaly distributing requests.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kwill/role-instance-restarts-due-to-os-upgrades, specifically the Common Issues #5 and associated code.

> If your website takes several minutes to warmup (either standard
> IIS/ASP.NET warmup of precompilation and module loading, or warming up
> a cache or other app specific tasks) then your clients may experience
> an outage or random timeouts.  After a role instance restarts and your
> OnStart code completes then your role instance will be put back in the
> load balancer rotation and will begin receiving incoming requests.  If
> your website is still warming up then all of those incoming requests
> will queue up and time out.  If you only have 2 instances of your web
> role then IN_0, which is still warming up, will be taking 100% of the
> incoming requests while IN_1 is being restarted for the Guest OS
> update.  This can lead to a complete outage of your service until your
> website is finished warming up on both instances.  It is recommended
> to keep your instance in OnStart, which will keep it in the Busy state
> where it won't receive incoming requests from the load balancer, until
> your warmup is complete.  You can use the following code to accomplish
> this:

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // For information on handling configuration changes
        // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.
        IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        string ip = null;
        foreach (IPAddress ipaddress in ipEntry.AddressList)
        {
            if (ipaddress.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
            {
                ip = ipaddress.ToString();
            }
        }

        string urlToPing = "http://" + ip;
        HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(urlToPing) as HttpWebRequest;
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks kwill, this is exactly what I was looking for. 
Due to deployement policy I won't be able to test it soon but I'll keep this post up to date when I got more results.

Comment: I tested it and it worked. I wrapped the content of this method inside a while([boolean]) to be sure it doesn't continue because of a TimeOutException.

Comment: This appears like a viable solution. When reading through it I was wondering why you'd like to get the/an IPv4 address and not just use `localhost` as a hostname?

Comment: Hi Jan.  The localhost binding is not setup, so that won't work.  You have to browse to the local IP address.

Comment: @kwill I am using your solution and its working fine for me. Just wanted to check if there are any disadvantages to this approach?

Comment: @kwill also i saw someone using thread.sleep before base.onStart(). Is it necessary? removing it worked as well for me

Comment: @kwill I have a health check which we are hitting every 30 seconds. I have some dependency injection code which can be initialized using health check request. I am thinking of using health check request to make sure all DB check are initialized since they are part of startup class. Do you see any issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but Cloud Services sits behind a load balancer. The load balancer has a probe feature that assess if an application instance can receive requests. You can configure the probe to make an http request to the application instance to check if the application is up or down, along with other settings.

-- Information about the load balancer

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/08/microsoft-azure-load-balancing-services/

-- Detail on the configuration in the Service Def

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj151530.aspx

Comment: thanks for the info.
we wen't for kwill solution but I'll take a look for the next time.

Comment: FYI, this solution won't work because of the issue described in my answer. During Guest OS update, if IN_0 is restarted and comes back to the Running state then IN_1 will proceed with restarting for the OS update. The state of your load balancer probe doesn't affect the role instance status, so even if your instance is out of LB rotation (because your site is still warming up) then you will still end up with both instances being down at the same time, resulting in a complete outage.  It is better to control the role instance status to prevent both instances being down.