# Application_Start loops when Azure web role starts up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, azure-cloud-services

We have an ASP.NET MVC application running in an Azure cloud service web role. There is a lot of startup code in `MvcApplication.Application_Start()`, doing database initialization among other things, and this can take a couple of minutes or more to run.

Sometimes, when a role instance starts up (either on deployment or following a restart), the application fails to start up first time. We can see from the logs that `Application_Start` fires, gets a certain way through, and then starts again from the beginning. After repeating this process a few times, the application does usually complete its startup routine and begin handling requests, but occasionally it gets into a seemingly never-ending loop, for which the only solution is to reboot or reimage the role instance.

We are *not* seeing any errors being logged, and `Application_End` is not firing at all. Serilog's [HttpRequestIdEnricher](https://github.com/serilog-web/classic/blob/master/src/SerilogWeb.Classic/Classic/Enrichers/HttpRequestIdEnricher.cs) is logging a different request ID each time `Application_Start` fires, indicating that there is a fresh `HttpContext.Current` each time. I have never seen this behaviour when running locally, only in Azure.

Any ideas what is going on?

### Update

This behaviour seems to happen only when multiple requests are being fired at the website. It most commonly (and infuriatingly) happens when a role instance in production is restarted; the UAT environment normally starts up fine, but I can provoke this issue by making multiple requests in different browser tabs. I also tried implementing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26793952/3248302) - making `WebRole.OnStart` ping the web URL to ensure the site was running before exiting - but that only ensured that the site *never* came up.

So my guess is that IIS is to blame: when a new request comes in while Application_Start is in progress, it seems to be restarting the application rather than letting the original request complete.

Comment: Can you check if Application_Error is called?

Comment: We are not handling Application_Error, but Everything in Application_Start is in a try/catch block with any exceptions logged, so I doubt it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have tracked this down to one or two settings in the IIS app pool configuration.

[image: IIS app pool ping settings]

I initially assumed `Startup Time Limit` was the most likely culprit, and tried setting that to 240 seconds (since our application typically takes 2-3 minutes to start up), but the problem persisted. I subsequently also changed `Ping Maximum Response Time` to 240 seconds, and that seems to have cured it.

When the startup got stuck in a loop there was usually (not always) a 2-minute interval between successive starts, so I assume IIS was waiting 30 seconds (the default `Ping Period`), then firing a request and waiting 90 seconds for a response, before restarting the worker process.

This Powershell code, in a script that runs when the web role starts up, configures the relevant settings:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | ForEach-Object {
    $appPool = "IIS:\AppPools\" + $_.Name
    $startupLimit = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 4
    Set-ItemProperty $appPool -Name processModel.startupTimeLimit -Value $startupLimit
    Set-ItemProperty $appPool -Name processModel.pingResponseTime -Value $startupLimit
}
```

It should be possible to do the same thing with `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager`, but I haven't tried.